# Получить значения выбранных checkbox после ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

Есть функция, которая получает часть таблицы с чекбоксами по аяксу.
Приходящее черз аякс виглядит примерно так

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='4'>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Арина ДУдаєва Ананнивна</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>ваи</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='3'></td>
  <td>3</td><td>Валєра Пупкин Иванович</td>
  <td>оформляем</td>
  <td>Крутой чувак</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='2'></td>
  <td>2</td><td>фиафива фивафивафвиа 12334</td>
  <td>афвиафивафвиаиф</td>
  <td>фивафивафиа</td>
</tr>
```

Первое поле в ряде это checkbox. 
Вопрос, как получить значения выбранных checkbox'ов через JQuery, после того, как пользователь нажмет на кнопку с id="send_selected_checkbox"?

Answer (score 2):

Взять элементы с атрибутом [:checked](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_checkbox_%D0%B8_radio) соответственно и взять у них `value`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#send_selected_checkbox', function(){
  var arrayOfChecked = [];
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {  
    arrayOfChecked.push(this.value)
    //console.log(this.value);    
  });
  
  console.log('arrayOfCheckedValues: ' + (arrayOfChecked.length > 0 ? arrayOfChecked: 'empty'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' value='4'>
  </td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Арина ДУдаєва Ананнивна</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>ваи</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' value='3'></td>
  <td>3</td><td>Валєра Пупкин Иванович</td>
  <td>оформляем</td>
  <td>Крутой чувак</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' value='2'></td>
  <td>2</td><td>фиафива фивафивафвиа 12334</td>
  <td>афвиафивафвиаиф</td>
  <td>фивафивафиа</td>
</tr>

<br/>
<br/>
<button id="send_selected_checkbox">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Выбрать все чекбоксы:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.check'); // по классу
document.querySelectorAll('[name=ankets_to_check]'); // по аттрибуту
```

2. Отфильтровать выбранные:

```
list = Array.from(list).filter(input => input.checked);
```

3. Отобразить элементы в значение атрибута val

```
list = list.map(input => input.getAttribute('val'));
```

---

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('send-btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name=ankets_to_check]'));
  
  console.log(Array.from(list)
    .filter(input => input.checked)
    .map(input => input.getAttribute('val')))
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='4'>
  <td>4<td>Арина ДУдаєва Ананнивна<td><td>ваи
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='3'>
  <td>3<td>Валєра Пупкин Иванович
  <td>оформляем
  <td>Крутой чувак
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='ankets_to_check' class='check' val='2'>
  <td>2</td><td>фиафива фивафивафвиа 12334
  <td>афвиафивафвиаиф
  <td>фивафивафиа
</table>

<button id="send-btn">Send</button>
```